# layout code for bank account jframe

Tags: java, swing

[image]

The image above is a screenshot of my bank account GUI. Basically I want initial balance, deposit label&field and withdraw label&field to be on different rows if that makes sense.

I've tried using different layouts but I can't get them to work and i'm not great with them.

What layout would be best to use for what I want?

```
package assignment;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class accountFrame extends JFrame 
    {
       private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
       private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 250;
       private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 0.00;
       double result;
       private JLabel initialLabel;
       private JLabel depositLabel;
       private JLabel withdrawLabel;
       private JTextField depositField;  
       private JTextField withdrawField;
       private JButton depositButton;
       private JButton withdrawButton;
       private final JLabel resultLabel;
       private JPanel controlPanel;
       private final cAccount account; 


       public accountFrame()
       { 

          account = new cAccount();      
          resultLabel = new JLabel("New Balance: £" + account.getBalance());

          createTextField();
          createButton();
          createControlPanel();
          setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
              setLocationRelativeTo(null);

       }

       private void createTextField()
       {
          final int FIELD_WIDTH = 5;

          initialLabel = new JLabel("Initial Balance £" + INITIAL_BALANCE);       
          depositLabel = new JLabel("Deposit: ");
          depositField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
              withdrawLabel = new JLabel("Withdraw: ");
              withdrawField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
       }

       private void createButton()
       {

               //Create deposit button and assign an action listener
          depositButton = new JButton("Deposit");

          class DepositListener implements ActionListener
          {
                 @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
             {     
                double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(depositField.getText());


                account.deposit(depositAmount);
                result = account.getBalance();
                resultLabel.setText("New Balance: " + result);
                    depositField.setText("0.00");
             }           
          }

          ActionListener d = new DepositListener();

          depositButton.addActionListener(d);     

              //Implement action listener for withdraw button
          withdrawButton = new JButton("Withdraw");

          class WithdrawListener implements ActionListener
          {
                 @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
             {    
                double withdrawl = Double.parseDouble(withdrawField.getText());

                    account.withdraw(withdrawl);

                result = account.getBalance();
                resultLabel.setText("New Balance: " + result);
                    withdrawField.setText("0.00");
             }           
          }

          ActionListener w = new WithdrawListener();
          withdrawButton.addActionListener(w);
       }

       private void createControlPanel()        
       {

          controlPanel = new JPanel();
          controlPanel.add(initialLabel);
          controlPanel.add(depositLabel);
          controlPanel.add(depositField);
          controlPanel.add(depositButton);
          controlPanel.add(withdrawLabel);
          controlPanel.add(withdrawField);
          controlPanel.add(withdrawButton);
          controlPanel.add(resultLabel);
          add(controlPanel);
       }

     }
```

Answer (score 5):

One way that I can say to design this would be to create the JFrame and add a JPanel into the JFrame. For this first JPanel you will declare it as a GridLayout 4 rows tall by 1 column across.

Next you can define new JPanels for each individual row and just use a regular old flow layout and allow the layout manage to handle those. Now if you want to get more finite in spacing etc you can by all means use a different layout to control down to a more hardset level.

The reason I like this method is because you can adjust each individual row as you like it. This is a very basic example but can be adjusted as much as you want.

```
public class Bank extends JFrame {
    JLabel initialBalance, balanceVal, deposit, withdrawl,newBalanceLbl, newBalanceField;
    JTextField txtDeposit, txtWithdrawl;
    JButton btnDeposit, btnWithdrawl;
    JPanel mainPanel, initialPanel, depositPanel, withdrawlPanel, newBalance;

    public Bank(){
        super("Bank Application");
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        mainPanel.add(configureInitial());
        mainPanel.add(configureDeposit());
        mainPanel.add(configureWithdrawl());
        mainPanel.add(configureNew());
        add(mainPanel);
        this.pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel configureInitial(){
        initialPanel = new JPanel();
        initialBalance = new JLabel("Inital Balance: ");
        balanceVal = new JLabel("0.00");
        initialPanel.add(initialBalance);
        initialPanel.add(balanceVal);
        return initialPanel;
    }

    private JPanel configureDeposit(){
        depositPanel = new JPanel();
        deposit = new JLabel("Deposit");
        txtDeposit = new JTextField(10);
        btnDeposit = new JButton("Deposit");
        depositPanel.add(deposit);
        depositPanel.add(txtDeposit);
        depositPanel.add(btnDeposit);
        return depositPanel;
    }

    private JPanel configureWithdrawl(){
        withdrawlPanel = new JPanel();
        withdrawl = new JLabel("Withdrawl");
        txtWithdrawl = new JTextField(10);
        btnWithdrawl = new JButton("Withdrawl");
        withdrawlPanel.add(withdrawl);
        withdrawlPanel.add(txtWithdrawl);
        withdrawlPanel.add(btnWithdrawl);
        return withdrawlPanel;
    }

    private JPanel configureNew(){
        newBalance = new JPanel();
        newBalanceLbl = new JLabel("New Balance: ");
        newBalanceField = new JLabel("0.00");
        newBalance.add(newBalanceLbl);
        newBalance.add(newBalanceField);
        return newBalance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bank();
    }

}
```

In general it will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is with a combination of [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) and [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html). I recommend you to try with different [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and also read [How to do a Runnable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't need to start from scratch to show you things like this (For example you could have removed unnecessary code from the one you posted here).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class LayoutsExample {
    JFrame frame;

    JPanel contentPanel;
    JPanel depositPanel;
    JPanel withdrawPanel;

    JLabel depositLabel;
    JLabel withdrawLabel;
    JLabel finalbalanceLabel;
    JLabel initialBalanceLabel;

    JTextField depositField;
    JTextField withdrawField;

    JButton depositButton;
    JButton withdrawButton;

    public static void main (String args[]) {       
        new LayoutsExample();
    }
    LayoutsExample () {
        frame = new JFrame("Layouts Example");
        depositPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        withdrawPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        depositLabel = new JLabel("Deposit: ");
        withdrawLabel = new JLabel("Withdraw: ");
        finalbalanceLabel = new JLabel("New Balance: ");
        initialBalanceLabel = new JLabel("Initial Balance: ");
        depositField = new JTextField("", 10);
        withdrawField = new JTextField("", 10);
        depositButton = new JButton("Deposit");
        withdrawButton = new JButton("Withdraw");

        depositPanel.add(depositLabel);
        depositPanel.add(depositField);
        depositPanel.add(depositButton);

        withdrawPanel.add(withdrawLabel);
        withdrawPanel.add(withdrawField);
        withdrawPanel.add(withdrawButton);

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        pane.add(initialBalanceLabel); //Added label to panel to center it

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.add(depositPanel);
        frame.add(withdrawPanel);

        pane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()); 
        pane.add(finalbalanceLabel); //Added label to pane to center it

        frame.add(pane);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```